# Pivot Dataframe for to_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this

```
          id_1    id_2    id_3   ...
date_1       1       3       4
date_2       4       6       3
date_3       5       7       1
...
```

I am also retrieving `test_id` from a SQL Server database with `SELECT @@IDENTITY;`

I want to append this data to an existing table in the same SQL Server database in this format

```
TEST_ID    DATE    ID    VALUE
test_id   date_1  id_1     1
test_id   date_1  id_2     3
test_id   date_1  id_3     4
test_id   date_2  id_1     4
test_id   date_2  id_2     6
test_id   date_2  id_3     3
test_id   date_3  id_1     5
test_id   date_3  id_2     7
test_id   date_3  id_3     1
```

How can I prepare the Dataframe so that [to sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) will write it to the table in the desired format?

I have tried resetting the index and pivoting, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `melt`  you original df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d=d.reset_index().melt('index')
d['TEST_ID']='TEST_ID'
d.rename(columns={'index': 'DATE', 'variable': 'ID'})

    Out[147]: 
     DATE    ID  value  TEST_ID
0  date_1  id_1      1  TEST_ID
1  date_2  id_1      4  TEST_ID
2  date_3  id_1      5  TEST_ID
3  date_1  id_2      3  TEST_ID
4  date_2  id_2      6  TEST_ID
5  date_3  id_2      7  TEST_ID
6  date_1  id_3      4  TEST_ID
7  date_2  id_3      3  TEST_ID
8  date_3  id_3      1  TEST_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack`

```
In [3023]: (df.stack().reset_index(name='VALUE')
              .rename(columns={'level_0': 'DATE', 'level_1': 'ID'})
              .assign(TEST_ID='test_id'))
Out[3023]:
     DATE    ID  VALUE  TEST_ID
0  date_1  id_1      1  test_id
1  date_1  id_2      3  test_id
2  date_1  id_3      4  test_id
3  date_2  id_1      4  test_id
4  date_2  id_2      6  test_id
5  date_2  id_3      3  test_id
6  date_3  id_1      5  test_id
7  date_3  id_2      7  test_id
8  date_3  id_3      1  test_id
```